# Best way to create subsites?

Tags: 7, subsites

What's the best way/module I can use to automatically create *subsites*, like drupalgardens.com.

Is there a module to do it? Can I use *drush* for this?

Comment: Do you need them to share the same database with the possibility of sharing content / users across sites or do you want the databases to be completely separate with no possibility of content / user sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like drupalgardens (aka new sites), you can use drush site-install, but you will still need to create the site directory and what not.

If you have a basic template for the new sites you should probably create an install profile or feature module and have it set everything up.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward and easiest way is to do it using [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/). Aegir helps you create subdomains, sites etc under various install profiles and servers. To get a taste of how it works, check this [Drupalcon london 2011 video](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/aegir-based-business-models).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact requirement..suggest you could also try using [domain access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module. You could use the same database and restrict or share your content across the domains created, restrict users to content of a specific domain, provides options for URL aliasing and redirects, it also has a feature named domain user that lets creation of a domain based on username. And all this does not involve creation of any additional settings.php or sites dirs.